# Querying Sparql dataset and caching results locally

Tags: sparql

1. During querying LOD datasets (using Sparql queries), we could face connection or server problems. Is there a reliable strategy that helps us to get data is a reliable way ?  I'm looking for a tool (in java) that helps to schedule querying tasks so that when an interruption occurs, the task will be re-run again until getting all data ?
2. I generally use Jena library to query remote Sparql dataset and use retrieved data to do some stuff. Is there a mechanism to automatically cache returned data so when I re-query the dataset with same query, data is retrieved from local cache instead of remote dataset endpoint.

Comment: you might be better asking this question on Stack Overflow

Comment: https://github.com/search?p=2&q=sparql+proxy&type=Repositories ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51789330/7879193